# Valid Email Regular Expression for ipad

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ipad

Hi I am using follwing regular expression to validate email address

```
@"^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$"
```

This works fine on all browsers on the pc. But it is giving problem on ipad on safari. It is even showing valid email id as invalid email id in ipad. so please tell me which is best regular expression for valid email on browsers on pc as well as ipad. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You try like this,

```
NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
```

`emailTest` will return true or false.....

Comment: i have solved this problem by using this Regex^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$ But i am surprised why this was working on all browsers while not just on ipad ???????